# Database specific volume

Tags: mysql, mariadb

I know that mariadb "datadir" will let me move the server default volume location. That is not my question. Is it possible to create each database with its own associated volume and locate that volume specific to its purpose. Think of a bunch of websites ... I'd like to locate the volume for the database for each website "near" that website content for ease of website re-location.

I have looked for "create database ... volume ... " but I don't find any such variant. I think one server per website would not scale vary well.

Any thoughts?

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Custom data directory is blade running. It requires a much higher than average administrator qualification - and I mean both database administrator and system administrator as/in one person.

Comment: Could look at something like [galera](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/galera) to have a read/write copy near every website.

Answer (score 1):

MariaDB supports a [`DATA DIRECTORY` option on the `CREATE TABLE` statement](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/create-table/#data-directoryindex-directory). Read the manual for details.

But this doesn't really put the data more "near the website" as you say. The data directory needs to be on a storage volume that can be used by the mysqld process on your database server.

For example, say you use AWS hosting, and you run a database server in us-east1. But the website application is running on EC2 instances in us-west1. Would it help to create a storage volume in us-west1, that is nearer the application, and mount that as a networked drive to the database server?

No, it would not help, it would make things worse. The queries are not executed by the storage. Queries are executed by the mysqld process on the database server (in us-east1) regardless of where the physical storage lives.

There is an unavoidable delay in long network hops, due to physics. With inefficiencies of network cables and switches, it's typically about 60 milliseconds latency between the US east coast and west coast. This affects every packet — sending the SQL query, and fetching results.

But if you host the storage near the application in us-west1, then the query execution has to incur further network delay, because reading bytes off of the storage needs to go across country *again*.